# Can't use arguments for "ls" in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I tried to redirect the output of `ls` to a file using `ls -l > file_list`. The file was created but no data was written to it. There was a warning that says `bash: export: '-l': not a valid identifier`. The only way I was able to write the output of the command `ls` to the file was to use `sudo` with it. Now, every time I try to use an argument with `ls`, the output is pretty much like

```
$ ls -la
Playlist2  Playlists
bash: export: '-la': not a valid identifier
```

and refuses to use the arguments unless I add sudo to it like `sudo ls -la`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have either an alias or a shell function called `ls` that is doing the wrong thing.

Have a look in your `.bashrc` file to see what's happening.

Use `type ls` in the shell to see if and what `ls` is an alias or function for.

Comment: Thanks. `ls` was aliased to `"export GLOBIGNORE_TMP=$GLOBIGNORE; 
export GLOBIGNORE=$GLOBIGNORE:.*:$(tr '\n' ':' < .hidden); 
ls -dC * ;export GLOBIGNORE=$GLOBIGNORE_TMP; export GLOBIGNORE_TMP=''` in `.bashrc`. I deleted it from there and now `ls` is working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @AlaskanBullWorm Huh, that's seriously convoluted and broken.

Comment: This even look like of some nasty virus trying to hide itself. You should start investigating your `.hidden` files and what you have inside them.

Comment: @AlaskanBullWorm What Patrick said. You may want to have a look at any file called `.hidden` and see what it (very clumsily) tried to hide from you.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek No, it's from [a post on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/359784/hide-files-in-linux-without-using-the-dot/816004#816004). But it is indeed seriously broken.